# Xml string to array, or to get his attributes

Tags: php, xml, xml-parsing

I have the following string:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<string xmlns="http://tempuri.org/UKash/Service1"><UKashTransaction><txCode>99</txCode><txDescription>Failed</txDescription><settleAmount> <settleAmount><transactionId>1341481253EDFC871620</transactionId><changeIssueVoucherNumber> <changeIssueVoucherNumber><changeIssueVoucherCurr> <changeIssueVoucherCurr><changeIssueAmount> <changeIssueAmount><changeIssueExpiryDate> <changeIssueExpiryDate><ukashTransactionId> <ukashTransactionId><currencyConversion> <currencyConversion><errCode>219</errCode><errDescription>Invalid Voucher Number</errDescription> <UKashTransaction></string></xml>
```

And I want to get some attributes of that string, like txDescrition, and so on, I tried different variations but can't get result. I am using php, if anyone can help I will really appreciate it since I am blocked.

UPDATE:

Problem is that I do not format string to be valid so I use curl and this is what I am getting from the gateway:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<string xmlns="http://tempuri.org/UKash/Service1">&lt;UKashTransaction&gt;&lt;txCode&gt;99&lt;/txCode&gt;&lt;txDescription&gt;Failed&lt;/txDescription&gt;&lt;settleAmount&gt;&lt;/settleAmount&gt;&lt;transactionId&gt;13414821393ED286BF2A&lt;/transactionId&gt;&lt;changeIssueVoucherNumber&gt;&lt;/changeIssueVoucherNumber&gt;&lt;changeIssueVoucherCurr&gt;&lt;/changeIssueVoucherCurr&gt;&lt;changeIssueAmount&gt;&lt;/changeIssueAmount&gt;&lt;changeIssueExpiryDate&gt;&lt;/changeIssueExpiryDate&gt;&lt;ukashTransactionId&gt;&lt;/ukashTransactionId&gt;&lt;currencyConversion&gt;&lt;/currencyConversion&gt;&lt;errCode&gt;219&lt;/errCode&gt;&lt;errDescription&gt;Invalid Voucher Number&lt;/errDescription&gt;&lt;/UKashTransaction&gt;</string>
```

Tnx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your XML is not well-formed - It's ending with a `</xml>` for which there's no starting `<xml>` element. Assuming you are correcting that, below code will solve your problem.

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($string);
print_r($xml->txDescrition);
```

Comment: yeap, it's not valid, since I'm getting strange info from gateway, do u know how to format it well ?

Comment: Use htmlspecialchars_decode() to decode the XML escape characters.

Answer (score 0):

If you have Simple XML (PHP should have it enabled by default), try this:

```
$xmlObject = simplexml_load_string($string);
echo $xmlObject->txDescription;
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-string.php